# tikz:arithmetic in calculating coordinates

Tags: tikz-pgf, arithmetic

Consider this example:

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\xstart{-1}
%  \def\xstart{-0.2-0.8}                                                                                                                                                                                   
%  \def\xstart{\pgfmathparse{-0.2-0.8}\pgfmathresult}                                                                                                                                                       
  \draw[fill=black](0,0)circle(0.1cm);
  \draw(\xstart, 1) rectangle (1, -1);
  \node at (0.5*\xstart + 1*0.5, 0){centre};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result is a centred text which is what we expect:

[image]

However, if I use `\def\xstart{-0.2-0.8}` some error manifests itself:

[image]

Rescue is also not provided by using `\def\xstart{\pgfmathparse{-0.2-0.8}\pgfmathresult}`.

How to correct this problem?

Comment: You could just use \pgfmathsetmacro\xstart{-0.2-0.8}

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat, appears to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two (out of several options) to remove the error.

1. Add parentheses, `\node at ({0.5*(\xstart) + 1*0.5}, 0){centre};`. This is because otherwise Ti*k*Z sees `\node at (0.5*-0.2-0.8 + 1*0.5, 0){centre};`. Note that you need to add braces around the x component since otherwise the parentheses confuse the parser.
2. Use `\pgfmathsetmacro`.

The results are the same.

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\xstart{-1}
  \def\xstart{-0.2-0.8}
%  \def\xstart{\pgfmathparse{-0.2-0.8}\pgfmathresult} 
  \draw[fill=black](0,0)circle(0.1cm);
  \draw(\xstart, 1) rectangle (1, -1);
  \node at ({0.5*(\xstart) + 1*0.5}, 0){centre};
  \begin{scope}[xshift=4cm]
    \pgfmathsetmacro\xstart{-0.2-0.8}
    \draw[fill=black](0,0)circle(0.1cm);
    \draw(\xstart, 1) rectangle (1, -1);
    \node at (0.5*\xstart + 1*0.5, 0){centre};
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: it seems `pgfmathsetmacro` is only needed for addition not multiplication

Comment: @Viesturs Here it is not needed to parse the expression because Ti*k*Z parses the coordinate. It is needed to first evaluate `-0.2-0.8`, and then do the multiplication. As I wrote, you can also achieve the same thing by putting parentheses around `-0.2-0.8`, and as you say, if you only multiply, it works simply because the issue does not arise.